# How do I get the first option of a select box to display in a div automatically when the page loads with JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html

Here's the code that I have at the moment. How can I get Apple to print below the select box automatically when the page loads?

```
<script>
function getOption() {
    var obj = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
    obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text;
}
</script>

<form>
Select your favorite fruit:
<select id="mySelect" onchange="getOption()">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
  <option>Pineapple</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
</select>
<br><br>
</form>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not using jquery, you can try this:

```
<script>
function getOption() {
    var obj = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
    obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
    getOption();
});
</script>
```

It's just calling your function once the page has loaded.

Comment: I tested this on JSFiddle, but I can't get it to work (here's the link http://jsfiddle.net/dhpototh/1/ )

Comment: @Natasha I think it's because you moved the script out of the HTML section like you originally had in your question. If you put it back there, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier for you to use jquery. The code will be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var value = $("#mySelect option:first").val();
    $("#mySelect").after("<div>"+value +"</div>");
});
```